# How does this smart contract have multiple contracts with one address?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

https://etherscan.io/address/0xabc1c404424bdf24c19a5cc5ef8f47781d18eb3e#code

Notice that this contract has:

- contract SafeMath
- contract BasicAccessControl
- contract EtheremonEnum
- contract EtheremonDataBase
- contract EtheremonData

All under one contract address. How would one deploy all of these to one contract address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one is actually deployed (`EthermonData`, in this case). It inherits from the other contracts.

`EthermonDataBase` inherits from some:

```
contract EtheremonDataBase is EtheremonEnum, BasicAccessControl, SafeMath
```

and then `EthermonData` inherits from that:

```
contract EtheremonData is EtheremonDataBase {
```

So the final contract that's deployed makes use of all of that code, but there's only one "contract" running.

See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance in the Solidity documentation.

Comment: I understand inheritance. But when deploying on https://remix.ethereum.org/ it makes you choose a specific contract: https://i.imgur.com/MAXsbG9.png

Comment: Yes. In this case, the specific contract that was chosen was `EthermonData`.

Comment: So although EthermonData was the one deployed.. technically all were deployed with it?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. Only `EthermonData` was deployed. Its code consists of code from a number of inherited contracts. (The source code could even include other contracts that it *doesn't* inherit from. The presence of those lines of code says nothing about what was deployed.)

Comment: Yes but my question from the screenshot I sent above then is so you have to individually deploy them? Because if I only deployed EthermonData which inherited from another contract. Wouldn't it break since none of the other contracts were deployed?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. When the compiler compiles `EthermonData`, it includes all the necessary code that was inherited. I don't know your programming background, but if you've used object-oriented programming languages before, it works just the same way.

Comment: Thank you. My confusion / concern was if the other inherited contracts would be uploaded to the blockchain automatically or if I would have to individually upload them. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

The compiler generates EVM bytecode from the contracts. Contracts are just a higher-level concept just like classes in object oriented languages.
EVM is not contract-aware.

Maybe you are confusing it with libraries, which are deployed and then called by relying contracts (using delegatecall)
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries